# Changing Variables for Lambda

Tags: python, variables, lambda, scipy

I'm writing a Python program using scipy (scipy.optimize.curve_fit). I have to fit multiple curves over a dataset, and then sum them up. The first step is finding all maxima, which is done. There will be at least one, but usually more. I want to generalise something like the following.

```
if (len(Maxima) == 1):
    f = lambda a, b, c : a * exp((b * x) + c)
else if (len(Maxima) == 2):
    f = lambda a, b, c, d, e, f : (a * exp((b * x) + c)) + (d * exp((e * x) + f)
```

And so forth. I need it so curve_fit will recognise that there are are (3 * Maxima) parameters, where it will then find them for me. There could be up to 20 curves or so, so doing the above statement is not practical.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:
Sorry, I missed out that the function has a dependency on the maxima. It's actually a Gaussian distribution centralised on each maxima.

I.e. a term is actually

```
f = (a * (Gamma ** 2) / (((E - Maxima[i])**2) + (b**2)))
```

And E is the independent variable that args must start with.

For example, for

```
len(Maxima) == 2
```

args would have to be,

```
E, a0, b0, Maxima[0], a1, b1, Maxima[1]
```

Sorry for my mistake.

Edit2:

I'm thinking something like this:

```
GaussianDistribution = lambda E, E0, I0, Sigma : (I0 * np.exp(-(((E - E0) / Sigma)**2)))
args = tuple([long] * ((len(Maxima) * 3) + 1))
d1, d2 = sc.curve_fit(GaussianDistribution(*args), Data[:, 0], Data[:, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lambda function that takes any number of arguments, using [arbitrary argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). You can then use a list comprehension to take the arguments three at a time, perform your operation on them, and then sum the result.

```
f = lambda *args: sum(args[i] * exp((args[i+1]*x)+args[i+2]) for i in range(0, len(args)-3, 3))
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed some information out. I added it to the introduction, because it was too long to post here.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this correct, you should be able to work with one lambda:

```
f = lambda a, b, c : a * exp((b * x) + c)
```

and then

```
result = sum(f(a, b, c) for a, b, c in maxima)
```

if `maxima` is of the form

```
maxima = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 9, 8)]
```

(which I guess).